# How do I keep track of what to differentiate in a Dirac Hamiltonian/Lagrangian?

Tags: field-theory, differentiation, dirac-equation, calculus, dirac-matrices

Suppose we have the dirac Hamiltonian:

$$
H = \int d^3y\bar\psi(y)_b(-i\gamma^k\partial_k+m)_{bc}\psi(y)_c.
$$

My question is should I think the derivative operator $\partial_k$ is acting on the coordinate $y$, or the spinor $\psi_c$? I'm trying to compute the commutator $C = [\psi^\dagger\psi,H]$, and have the step

$$
C = \int d^3y\delta^3(x-y)(-i\gamma^k\gamma^0)_{bc}\partial_k[\psi_b^\dagger(x)\psi_c(y)-\psi_b^\dagger(y)\psi_c(x)].
$$

I'm having trouble differentiating this part, and I think it would be great to know how that derivative operator is acting on the spinors.

Comment: The derivative is with respect to $y$, which is an argument of the function $\psi$. It's just like "$d f(x)/dx$" in introductory calculus.

Comment: the RHS of your final equation for C has free indices $b$ and $c$. Are there supposed to be some indices hanging on the LHS (and on the RHS of the definition for C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spinor $\psi$ is a $\mathbb{C}^4$-valued function of the coordinates, with components $\psi_a(y)$. The derivative then acts componentwise differentiating the standard functions $\psi_a(y)$ with respect to their argument. There is absolutely nothing fancy here, just standard multivariable calculus.

Maybe you are confused about when you promote $\psi$ to an operator, as it looks like you are doing that. In that case the only thing that happens is that the entries of the $\mathbb{C}^4$-tuple become operators depending on the coordinates. The derivative acts upon then in the appropriate way as derivatives act on operator-valued functions.